# Inserting android POJO in firebase results in json list of values

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, pojo

I am using the following class in my android project to upload data into its firebase backend.

```
public class IATFPojo {

public Double ecc, ecc2;
public boolean prenhes, ressinc;
public Long diasp, cl;
public String localiza, datacob;

public IATFPojo() {}

public IATFPojo(double ecc, boolean prenhes, boolean ressinc, long diasp, String localiza, String datacob, double ecc2, long cl){

    this.ecc = ecc;
    this.ecc2 = ecc2;

    this.prenhes = prenhes;
    this.ressinc = ressinc;

    this.diasp = diasp;
    this.cl = cl;

    this.localiza = localiza;
    this.datacob = datacob;
}

public Double getEcc() {
    return ecc;
}

public Double getEcc2() {
    return ecc2;
}

public boolean isPrenhes() {
    return prenhes;
}

public boolean isRessinc() {
    return ressinc;
}

public Long getDiasp() {
    return diasp;
}

public Long getCl() {
    return cl;
}

public String getLocaliza() {
    return localiza;
}

public String getDatacob() {
    return datacob;
}
}
```

And I am inserting it in firebase like this:

```
DatabaseReference myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

IATFPojo pojo = new IATFPojo(
                    //ecc, prenhes, ressinc, diasp, localiza, datacob, ecc2, cl
                    (map.get("IATF6")).length() > 0 ? Double.parseDouble(map.get("IATF6")) : 0,
                    Integer.parseInt(map.get("IATF20")) > 1,
                    Integer.parseInt(map.get("IATF5")) > 1,
                    Long.parseLong(map.get("IATF30")),
                    map.get("IATF23"),
                    map.get("IATF1"),
                    (map.get("IATF22")).length() > 0 ? Double.parseDouble(map.get("IATF22")) : 0,
                    Long.parseLong(map.get("IATF21"))
            );

myRef.child(uid +"/MULTIPARA").child(map.get("IATF1")+"_"+map.get("SUI")).setValue(pojo);
```

It creates a node with the user id (uid) and another node with the reference (MULTIPARA), and then the child which contains the data using the format date_animal id.
The problem is that the data is being stored like this in the firebase:

[image: real time database]

And as I understood the data should have the IATFPojo keys like this:

```
2016-11-11_     A    335

ecc: 2.75

ecc2: 3

prenhes: true

ressinc : false

diasp: 52

cl: -1

localiza: "16 IATF BV 5"

datacob: "2016-11-11"
```

Am I missing something in the configuration of the class, or in firebase ?

Comment: You should remove the whitespace from `map.get("SUI")`, by the way

Comment: Thank you, but not yet. I am starting to use a NoSQL database and the whitespaces are part of the animal's id layout.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what difference `2016-11-11_     A    335` vs `2016-11-11_ A335` will make as long as you query consistently, but okay... Anyways, you can use Firebase annotations to label the fields, but it should work with the code you have. Are you using proguard to obfuscate your objects?

Comment: Yes I am using proguard, and included the -keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*

Comment: It's very possible proguard renamed your fields into a-z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cricket_007's comments lead me to the answer. I have created a new package in my android project to include all POJO classes to upload to firebase and then included the following line to my proguard rules:

```
-keepnames class newPackage.** { *; }
```

So now all my android POJOs are being uploaded to firebase with the correct field keys.

Thank you cricket_007.